# Using Mule 4 Insert/update is not working to Heroku Postgresql

Tags: mule

I tried with different Driver versions, mule versions, different tables but, not able to do insert/update from Mule to Heroku-Postgresql.

I tried with Java code to insert on Heroku-postgresql to check any write access issue but, this works fine.

Same application I tried with local postgreql everything is working fine with local postgresql but, not with heroku postgresql.

Note: If I do not set input parameter and set hard coded values then it works heroku also.

What is the problem with Mule and Heroku postgresql with input parameter values?
I am not getting any error, no exception so,[enter image description here][1] not able to understand the problem.

please help me on this, I am stuck.

Input Parameter values I am trying to set as:

```
    {
  "Id":payload.Id,  
  "AccountId": payload.AccountId,
  "OwnerId": payload.OwnerId,
  "ContractId": payload.ContractId,
  "Pricebook2Id": payload.Pricebook2Id,
  "OrderNumber": payload.OrderNumber,  
  "IsReductionOrder": payload.IsReductionOrder as Boolean,
  "Status": payload.Status,  
  "Name": payload.Name,
  "TotalAmount": payload.TotalAmount,
  "EffectiveDate":payload.EffectiveDate as Date
}
```

Mule configuration:

```
    <db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="db823135-d287-439f-ad77-76652012b66f" >
        <db:generic-connection url="xxx" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" user="xxx" password="xxx" />
    </db:config>
    <flow name="testherokuFlow" doc:id="5ac6fe61-525a-4ede-8163-43ad4d402f76" >
        <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" doc:id="27b640f6-f8b2-4e06-9c44-ddf5941b99c7" >
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <fixed-frequency frequency="15" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <set-payload value='#[{
  "Id": "8012w000000De1qAAC",
  "AccountId": "0012w00000KY8kFAAT",
  "OwnerId": "0052w000006WxYiAAK",
  "ContractId": "8002w000000YBG6AAO",
  "Pricebook2Id": "01s2w00000C4oj9AAB",
  "OrderNumber": "00000101",  
  "IsReductionOrder": "false",
  "TotalAmount": "110000.0",
  "EffectiveDate": "2020-09-24",
  "Status": "Draft",  
  "Name": null,
  "BillingCity": null,
  "ActivatedDate": null,
  "ShipToContactId": null,
  "CompanyAuthorizedById": null,
  "CustomerAuthorizedDate": null,
  "BillingPostalCode": null,
  "ShippingStreet": null,
  "CustomerAuthorizedById": null,
  "ShippingPostalCode": null,
  "ShippingState": null,
  "BillingState": null,
  "BillingAddress": null,
  "ShippingCountry": null,
  "ShippingCity": null,
  "OrderReferenceNumber": null,
  "OriginalOrderId": null,
  "CompanyAuthorizedDate": null,
  "BillToContactId": null,
  "EndDate": null,
  "BillingCountry": null,
  "BillingStreet": null,
  "ShippingAddress": null
}]' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="94fc6b1f-eb99-427e-afad-79cca35ec130" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="f14f263b-baad-4ad3-94dc-c65546f3dfb2" message="Insert in progress"/>
        <db:insert doc:name="Insert" doc:id="7d1f1a43-b257-4a6d-83c0-dc48d652e44a" config-ref="Database_Config">
            <db:sql ><![CDATA[insert into sf_order (id, account_id, owner_id,contract_id,pricebook2_id,order_number,is_reduction_order,status, name, total_amount, effective_date) 
VALUES (:Id, :AccountId, :OwnerId,:ContractId,:Pricebook2Id,:OrderNumber,:IsReductionOrder,:Status, :Name, :TotalAmount,:EffectiveDate) ]]></db:sql>
            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[{
    "Id":payload.Id,
    "AccountId":payload.AccountId,
    "OwnerId":payload.OwnerId,
    "ContractId":payload.ContractId,
    "Pricebook2Id":payload.Pricebook2Id,
    "OrderNumber":payload.OrderNumber,
    "IsReductionOrder":if(payload.IsReductionOrder==null or payload.IsReductionOrder=="null") ("false" as Boolean) else (payload.IsReductionOrder) as Boolean,
    "Status":payload.Status,
    "Name":payload.Name,
    "TotalAmount":payload.TotalAmount,
    "EffectiveDate":payload.EffectiveDate as Date
}]]]></db:input-parameters>
        </db:insert>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="f6cc1c2e-f99d-425e-9b8b-b6bfa756caeb" message="Insert done"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Hi, please share the flow in XML (not an screenshot please) including the configurations, excluding confidential data like host names and credentials.

Comment: here it is :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TOKw-wqumLufVJ8FwU8qVNXTKBzKW8Za/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I meant by editing the question ;-)

Comment: The problem that I am facing is when I set values with single quotes which are hard coaded values ('value1', 'value2') then value1 and value2 gets inserted in respective column.
But, when I make it dynamic as values(:value1, :value2) 
here value1 and value2 are place holders and there actual content is set in 
 input parameter  as:
#[{
"value1": "aa",
 "value2": "bb"
}]

Then It dosent works for me. It not even gives any error and data is also not inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters ids being set are not matching the case for the ids being using in the insert. Try to make both match case.

For example `"Id":payload.Id` set `Id` but the query uses `(id,` (lower case 'i').

Make them both 'Id' or both 'id'.

Comment: Finally after long time and strange surprises I understant what was not working.
1. As I mention there was no error/exception also no insertion was happeniing.
This time I kept application running after insert connector is reached. And after 2 minutes I found the insertion was complete. 
Now the question is why 2 minutes? However, I believe It should not have anything to do with mule.